# c# IList not generating as intended

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach, windows-forms-designer

Basic Gist: User browses to CSV, app reads CSV, parses does some calcs and then spits out a new csv. This is a windows Form app using c# flavoured .net.

CSV File being Tested:

```
Position,Title3,Title1,Title2,Title4,Title5,,
1,P-D3101A,NAME 1,175,282.9280381,1 x 30 x 120
2,P-D3103A,NAME 2,37.2,60.14241724,30 x 16
3,P-D3102A,NAME 3,29.8,48.17860306,30 x 10
4,P-D2301A,NAME 4,35,56.58560762,30 x 16
5,P-D1201A,NAME 5,38,61.43580256,30 x 16
6,P-D2301D,NAME 6,32,51.73541268,30 x 16
7,A-D0636,NAME 7,8.5,13.74221899,30 x 1.5
```

Have a class:

```
class Equipment
{
    public string Title1 { get; set; }
    public double Title2 { get; set; }
    public string Title3 { get; set; }
}
```

and a parser (thanks very much to SO community) :

```
static IList<Equipment> Parse(string[] input)
{
    var result = new List<Equipment>();

    var header = input[0].Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim().ToLower()).ToList();
    var title1Loc = GetIndexOf(header, "title1");
    var title2Loc = GetIndexOf(header, "title2");
    var title3Loc = GetIndexOf(header, "title3");


    foreach (var s in input.Skip(1))
    {
        var line = s.Split(',');
        result.Add(new Equipment
        {
            Title1 = line[title1Loc].Trim(),
            Title2 = double.Parse(line[title2Loc]),
            Title3 = line[title3Loc].Trim(),
        });
    }
    return result;
}

static int GetIndexOf(IList<string> input, params string[] needles)
{
    return Array.FindIndex(input.ToArray(), needles.Contains);
}
```

and a couple of buttons, one is to get the file and save its file path in the string referenceFile , the other is to parse the data:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(referenceFile);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data), "Your CSV");
    }
```

Ultimately I want to produce a new CSV File, which I can although its blank, so to check what its getting from the parsed data I used a message box which displays:

> MyProject.Form1+Equipment

repeated 7 times on new lines.  So it is correctly going over my 7 line file, however not actually generating what I want.  Any glaring errors I cant see?

Comment: The default ToString implementation for a class will output the class's name.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to [override the `ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method of to `Equipment` class to get the desired output which dictates that how the string representation of your type should look like.

Here is how it can look like as an example:

```
class Equipment
{
    public string Title1 { get; set; }
    public double Title2 { get; set; }
    public string Title3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"{Title1},{Title2},{Title3}";
    }
}
```